Non-Food related items
Not addressed by Transfer of taste to/from non-food items
Can non-food related objects have the status of milchig or fleishig because of saliva or food residue? This would refer to anything from a toothbrush to a pipe to the cover of a siddur or a teething toy. None of these is primarily meant as a food-related item but all make contact with the mouth and can therefore be in contact with meat or milk particles which might then being in contact with the "other" on subsequent use (unless you have one pipe for after meat meals and one for after dairy).
Would this be like cutlery, or is there a distinction because a fork is designed to be in longer contact with food (or because it is washed in hot water)?

AFAIK, nothing becomes "milchig" or "fleishig" without it touching hot milk or meat food items

So if I eat a big hamburger and then, mid chew smoke my corncob pipe (with the grease and grossness on my mouth) I can, the next day, get ice cream all over my face and smoke the same pipe?

In that case, the pipe wouldn't be fleishig. The meat, which is still currently on the pipe, obviously is (assuming it's still edible for dogs)
